# SQL Server money cell * percentage cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just a quick question, say you have multiple rows of a value and multiple rows of a percentage in a table, for example 1 being £1000 and the percentage being 100%. I want to calculate this use an SQL query.

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.money* Table2.percentage)Answer FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID= Table2.ID
WHERE ID2= 3;
```

the above sql statement will basically * the money by 100 giving me a value of £10,000 which is incorrect, cant seem to get my head around a simple method, thanks for any help guys

I want to calculate the money * by the percentage, so in this case the answer should be £2000 as it is * the value by 100%. if the percentage was 50% I would expect the answer to be £1500 and so on....

Comment: what do you want to calculate. Please try to be more clear.

Comment: In your example, are you multiplying money with 100? Since it is percent you have to divide by 100 as well.

Comment: If your percentage is 100 and you want it to be 100% you can always divide by 100 afterwards, that's all a percentage is anyway, a number out of 100. `SUM(Table1.money* Table2.percentage / 100) AS Answer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name "per cent" suggests, mathematically 100% = 1, i.e. the whole. If you have a percentage in a column, you shoud divide it by 100 before doing any maths on it. i suggest:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
            Table1.money * (1+(Table2.percentage/100.0))
       ) Answer 

FROM Table1

INNER JOIN Table2 
     ON Table1.ID= Table2.ID

WHERE ID2= 3;
```

Comment: the answer above will divide 100 by 100 giving me 1, which would leave the answer at £1000

Comment: cheers pal, its quite a simple but my brain is having a moment haha

Comment: Just in case his percentage column is an integer you might want to make it `100.0` so it becomes a float and avoids truncating, `50/100 = 0` in integer division.

Comment: it is a float already, just thought id ask it like above to get the general query right... thanks